# SSRS BIDS 2008 Bubble chart - Bubble size range

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting, bids, bubble-chart

I have a bubble chart in SSRS BIDS 2008. Is it possible to set ranges for example:

10-50 = bubble size 10, 51-100 = bubble size 20,
etc, etc....

I have set the BubbleMaxSize and BubbleMinSize properties however I am finding that as my ranges are very close in amount it is hard to distinguish slightly bigger ones than smaller ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the series for your bubble chart to get the Series Properties dialog. The first pane, Series Data, has a field for Bubble size.

Use the Function button next to the text box (fx) to pop up another dialog, where you can enter something like:

```
=SWITCH(
 Fields!SizeField.Value > 100, 4,
 Fields!SizeField.Value > 50, 3,
 Fields!SizeField.Value > 10, 2,
 Fields!SizeField.Value > 0, 1)
```

The bubble chart evaluates the range of values returned by this field and then will map these sizes accordingly. So my formula will give four distinct sizes between BubbleMinSize and BubbleMaxSize.